# Wordpress - Which file outputs the entire HTML Document content?

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for the file that outputs the entire HTML Document from `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the `</html>` tag to the screen, including the header, footer and the page content.

I know that pages are powered by template files, and header and footer have their own files (header.php & footer.php)

But which file outputs all of it on the screen?

Comment: Pretty much all pages does,bit if you are looking interms of hierarchy index.php is the main file..

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the page being viewed. Take a look at this [WP template heirarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/) document to see which top level template is used for which page type.